# Set default options for WinRar

Tags: compression, rar, winrar

Is there some method for setting the default extraction properties for WinRar?  I want to make it so that I can open a rar file, press Alt-W and have it decompress to a default location and have it automatically 'Wait if other WinRAR copies are active'.

I already know about creating a default Compression profile in Setting -> Compression -> Create Default... - but this seems to only be the profile for compression - not decompression.

Thanks in advance!
William

Comment: Which version you are using? It will be worth to find out the solution regading that.

Comment: The latest one.

Answer (score 2):

As of 4.20, there's a button "Save settings" in "Extraction path and options\General". This is the dialog that pops up asking for extraction settings. "Advanced"-tab settings will also be saved.

However, this does not save the set path. To alter this behavior, look in "Settings\Compression". You can enter two paths there, a "Default folder for archives" and a "Default folder for extracted files".
You can also change if the program creates subdirectories named after the archive and if it should prevent redundant subfolders ("Extract to *\"-folder will be prevented if it would contain nothing but another folder with the same name).